# How to defer an mgo Session until it's fully streamed to the client?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, revel, defer-keyword

I want to close an mgo session after it' fully streamed to the client. At first, I thought this might work, but it seems the `defer` just waits until the the func begins to return or something.

```
func (c App) OpenFile(fileId string) revel.Result {
    // convert string to bson.ObjectId
    objId := bson.ObjectIdHex(fileId)
    file, session := OpenFile(objId)
    defer session.Close()
    // memfile io.Reader, filename string, delivery ContentDisposition, modtime time.Time
    var now = time.Now()
    return c.RenderBinary(file, "filename", "inline", now)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your `OpenFile` function doing but I assume it using Mongo's GridFS to access the file. You are right `defer session.Close()` is called right before the return. If you use file Revel [closes it automatically](https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/a9a2ff45fae4330ef4116b257bcf9c82e53350c2/results.go#L349) but in your case, you also want to close the session.

The only one way around it is to make custom Reader that can be used by Revel in `RenderBinary`. Something like:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

type MongoReader struct {
    io.Reader
    File    *os.File
    Session *mgo.Session
}

func (mr *MongoReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, e error) {
    return mr.File.Read(p)
}

func (mr *MongoReader) Close() {
    mr.File.Close()
    mr.Session.Close()
}

func main() {
    mr := MongoReader{}
    mr.Session, mr.File = OpenFile("abababa")
    return c.RenderBinary(mr, "filename", "inline", now)
}
```

I didn't test it on Revel but as code is quite simple I think it should work. Maybe you will need some `os.File` specific methods.